# Reading json with a key in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam making a dictionary game in unity 3d. And i have a json file about all the definitions and examples of all vocabulary.Each word has key is the word it self ( which i highlighted). how can i get the value of each word(key). I have created an oject for json.

for example: i have a word "a cappella" it give me back:

a cappella

1: adverb

definition :without musical accompaniment

example : they performed a cappella

2 :adjective

definition :sung without instrumental accompaniment

example : they sang an a cappella Mass.

many thanks

Here is the model I use for the JSON

```
public class VocabularyModel : MonoBehavior
{
    public string Word { get; set; }

    public string WordId {get; set; }

    public Meaning[] Meanings { get; set; }

    public Label[] Labels { get; set; }
}
```

json String

{
    "a cappella": {
        "word": "a cappella",
        "wordset_id": "5feb6f679a",
        "meanings": [
            {
                "id": "492099d426",
                "def": "without musical accompaniment",
                "example": "they performed a cappella",
                "speech_part": "adverb"
            },
            {
                "id": "0bf8d49e2e",
                "def": "sung without instrumental accompaniment",
                "example": "they sang an a cappella Mass",
                "speech_part": "adjective"
            }
        ]
    },
    "AD": {
        "word": "AD",
        "wordset_id": "76c6ebfae9",
        "meanings": [
            {
                "id": "4c21c72afa",
                "def": "in the Christian era",
                "speech_part": "adverb",
                "synonyms": [
                    "A.D.",
                    "anno Domini"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "A.D.": {
        "word": "A.D.",
        "wordset_id": "b7e9d406a0",
        "meanings": [
            {
                "id": "a7482f3e30",
                "def": "in the Christian era",
                "speech_part": "adverb",
                "synonyms": [
                    "AD"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

}

Comment: Both of the images you posted are the same. You should not be posting code as images, it makes it harder to see and answer the question. I have a pending edit to include the code for the model. Could you please add the JSON image as text to the question?

Comment: In unity, use fields, not properties for Json, properties don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a library or you wrote the code yourself?
In the second case, I'd suggest to use Json.NET from Newtonsoft.

You can deserialize the JSON to a JObject and then treat it as if it was a dictionary.

To do this, you can structure your JSON in the following way:

```
{
    "a_cappella" : {
        "word" : "a cappella",    
        "wordId" : "123",
        "meanings" : {...},
        "labels" : {...}
    }
    "building" : {
        "word" : "building",    
        "wordId" : "124",
        "meanings" : {...},
        "labels" : {...}
    }
}
```

Then you deserialize into a JObject and search what you need:

```
var json = // here is your json string
var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); 

if (dictionary.ContainsKey("a_cappella")){
    return dictionary["a_cappella"].ToObject<VocabularyModel>();
}
```

Comment: Json support in unity is crippled, you can't use Newtonsoft.

Comment: it works well. However with

var dictionary = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

i have to call it everytime i move to another methol if i want to use "dictionary " is there any way to make var dictionary become a global variable ? 
big help

Comment: Good to hear eragon. To make it global variable you can make it static and put it in a place reachable from all the code. By the way, try to publish the project and see if it works also there. This might be what @RonBeyer was talking about.